# Looping over a list of keys to extract from a JSON file with jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, loops, jq

I'm trying to extract a series of properties (named in an input file) in jq and getting error when I feed those from bash via a loop:

```
while read line; do echo $line; cat big.json | jq ".$line"; sleep 1; done < big.properties.service

cfg.keyload.service.count
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

When i try to do it manually it works

```
$ line=cfg.keyload.service.count
$ echo $line
cfg.keyload.service.count
$ cat big.json | jq ".$line"
1
```

Is there any way to get it work in loop?

Here is example

```
cat >big.json <<EOF
{
  "cfg": {
    "keyload": {
      "backend": {
    "app": {
      "shutdown": {
        "timeout": "5s"
                  },
      "jmx": {
        "enable": true
                    }
           }
       }
     }
}
}
EOF

cat >big.properties.service <<EOF
cfg.keyload.backend.app.shutdown.timeout
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.enable
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.nonexistent
cfg.nonexistent
EOF
```

...output should be:

```
cfg.keyload.backend.app.shutdown.timeout
"5s"
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.enable
true
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.nonexistent
null
cfg.nonexistent
null
```

Comment: There's no good reason to do the looping in bash instead of in jq.

Comment: Please try to add a [mcve] -- complete code someone else can run themselves to see your problem, just as my answer creates input files needed to test that it works.

Comment: It also would be helpful to run your script with `bash -x yourscript` to log every command it runs. If, for instance, your input has DOS newlines instead of Windows newlines, that log will make it obvious.

Comment: `cat` does not show nonprintable characters on its own. If you're on a GNU system, use `cat -A` -- or, as I suggested before, amend in logs from `bash -x yourscript` showing the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Immediate Issue - Invalid Input

The "invalid character" at hand here is almost certainly a carriage return. Use `dos2unix` to convert your input file to a proper UNIX text file, and your original code will work (albeit very inefficiently, rereading your whole `big.json` every time it wants to extract a single property).

#### Performant Implementation - Loop In JQ, Not Bash

Don't use a bash loop for this at all -- it's much more efficient to have `jq` do the looping.

Note the `sub("\r$"; "")` used in this code to remove trailing carriage returns so it can accept input in DOS format.

```
jq -rR --argfile infile big.json '
sub("\r$"; "") as $keyname
| ($keyname | split(".")) as $pieces
| (reduce $pieces[] as $piece ($infile; .[$piece]?)) as $value
| ($keyname, ($value | tojson))
' <big.properties.service
```

properly emits as output, when given the inputs in the question:

```
cfg.keyload.backend.app.shutdown.timeout
"5s"
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.enable
true
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.nonexistent
null
cfg.nonexistent
null
```

Comment: That works. Great thanks to you. But could please you explain syntax you used in jq.
And is there any way to "echo" each line in loop?

Comment: What's your real goal, with respect to the `echo`s? If you want to intersperse the keys with the outputs, that's easy enough. (Personally, I'd generate tab-separated output, putting each key and its value on the same line).

Comment: ...as for the jq syntax, it's all documented at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/. Feel free to ask a specific question that you still have after reading that documentation.

Comment: my goal is to validate params file with json. For example if i do
    `cat big.json | jq '.cfg.keyload.service.count.foo'`
i get null because there is no such key in json. But if is use your syntax and put defunct param i get empty value, not null. Can you explain how to get null on nonexisting key?

Comment: So that way when i will get 
      `cfg.keyload.backend.app.shutdown.timeout  5s`
      `cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.enable        true` 
      `cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.enabled      NULL`
      `cfg.keyload.backend.pepe.jmx.enable       false` 
I will raise alarm on NULL value assuming there is no such key.

Comment: That said, if you want that behavior, you should edit the question to show it -- ie. have an example with "null" output in the question itself. Otherwise, it's not part of the specification you asked answers to follow, so an answer can be correct/valid even if it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your properties file is effectively paths in the json that you want to retrieve values from. Convert them to paths that `jq` recognizes so you can get those values. Just make an array of keys that would need to be traversed.  Be sure to read your properties file as raw input (`-R`) since it's not json, and use raw output (`-r`) to be able to output the paths as you want.

```
$ jq --argfile big big.json '
    ., (split(".") as $p | $big | getpath($p) | tojson)
' -Rr big.properties.service
cfg.keyload.backend.app.shutdown.timeout
"5s"
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.enable
true
cfg.keyload.backend.app.jmx.nonexistent
null
cfg.nonexistent
null
```